# Operador logico OR em sparql

Tags: sql, query, sparql

Estou a tentar construir uma query em sparql utilizando Or, do tipo:

```
SELECT ?a ?b ?c
WHERE (?a :property ?b **OR** ?b :property ?c **OR** ?a :property ?x OR .....)
...
```

ms não consigo utilizar, porque lança o seguinte erro:

```
Encountered " "or" "or "" at line 9, column 25.
Was expecting one of: 
...
```

como posso faze-lo?

Comment: este é o site do SO em português, por favor traduza a sua pergunta

Comment: feito :) <3 :)))